# Building Dockerfile on "RUN apt-get ..." step gives me "jailing process inside rootfs caused 'permission denied': unknown"

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt

I installed docker using snap on Ubuntu 19.04 and ensured that my user has access to the docker group. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
```

I issue this command:

> docker build .

And I get this output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> d131e0fa2585
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 1e6a5d173b4c
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:109: jailing process inside rootfs caused \\\"permission denied\\\"\"": unknown
```

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Why don't you use an official nginx container?

Comment: I went ahead and removed all reference to Nginx because it is a red herring. This is strictly a problem with docker on Ubuntu 19.04. I want to do more things with docker than just Nginx.

Comment: The snap is probably broken. Do a normal Docker installation.

Comment: I repeated every step on Ubuntu 18.04 as a docker host and everything works perfectly. It would seem that Ubuntu 19.04 is not ready for prime time.